# Change Gitlab CI Runner user in subprocess

Tags: gitlab

I have the following problem on my CentOS VM.

In the VM I run the process gitlab-runner as root - see my systemd service.

```
root@runner1:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service | sed 's/^/    /'
[Unit]
Description=GitLab Runner
After=syslog.target network.target
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/usr/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner

[Service]
StartLimitInterval=5
StartLimitBurst=10
ExecStart=/usr/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner "run" "--working-directory" "/home/gitlab-runner/builds/" "--config" "/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml" "--service" "gitlab-runner" "--syslog" "--user" "root"

Restart=always
RestartSec=120

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Some builds require root permissions to create or delete files at certain locations. Now gitlab-runner always throws errors. The reason is that the process gitlab-runner, although started as root, does sub-processes running as user gitlab-runner. Here is a snippet of my pipeline logfile

```
$ id -u
997
$ whoami
gitlab-runner
$ rm -rf /tmp/*
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/ks-script-1yMUS_’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/ks-script-jNgpQ5’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/systemd-private-1838297d1ab047a99c3628869e77fd18-chronyd.service-z1RO0u’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/tmp.THBemf0N5O’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/yum.log’: Operation not permitted
```

How can I prevent gitlab-runner from starting sub-processes under another user?

Volker

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, 
if gitlab-runner is executed as root, the workspace must not be located in another home directory.

I have now changed the system as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=GitLab Runner
After=syslog.target network.target
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/usr/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner

[Service]
StartLimitInterval=5
StartLimitBurst=10
ExecStart=/usr/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner "run" "--working-directory" "/root/builds/" "--config" "/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml" "--service" "gitlab-runner" "--syslog" "--user" "root"

Restart=always
RestartSec=120

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now the process finally runs as a real user. To the developers, it would be useful to give at least some information why the service does not run as root but as gitlab-runner.